# Dictionary with multiple levels to pandas data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have created a dictionary after processing data

```
# group data based on customer_id
g = df.groupby(["CUSTOMER_ID"])
dataset = {}
for customer_name, group in g:
    
    group_data={"month":[], "input":[], "output":[]}
    
    # for each group sort data based on month_period
    sort_ = group.sort_values(by=["MONTH_PERIOD"], ascending=True)
    
    # move customer_id at the end of the dataframe (to take it easily)
    columns=len(sort_.columns)
    column_to_move = sort_.pop("CUSTOMER_ID")
    sort_.insert(columns-1, "CUSTOMER_ID", column_to_move)
    
    # avoid the last element to not running out memory
    for ind in range(len(sort_)-1):
        group_data["month"].append(sort_.iloc[ind][0])
        group_data["input"].append(sort_.iloc[ind][1:-2].values)
        group_data["output"].append(sort_.iloc[ind+1][-2])
    
    dataset[customer_name] = group_data
```

however, i don't know how can i get everything together in one data frame ?

Sorry for being naive as I tried

```
customer_=np.asarray(customer_)
input_=np.asarray(input_)
output_=np.asarray(output_)
month_=np.asarray(month_)
```

also i tried

```
pd.DataFrame([dataset])
```

[image]

but it does not give my needed data frame in features in columns.
where i have customers, months in and other features in columns

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input data and expected output?

Comment: try just pd.DataFrame(dataset), I think that should work, since you dont have nested data, inside the lists. If not I think you can try pd.json_normalize(). https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte I tried but then i get output like above in description